CustomerResponse is duplicated for every address record
I have the following query:
var query = from customer in _unitOfWork.customerRepository.All()
            join adresses in _unitOfWork.AdresRepository.All() on customer.adressNo equals adresses.adressNo into adr
            from adresses in adr.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new CustomerResponse
                       {
                           CustomerName = customer.Name
                           Select new Address
                                      {
                                          adressName = adr.name
                                          adressNo = adr.Number
                                      }
                       }

The CustomerResponse is duplicated for every address. What I want is one CustomerResponse with multiple addresses as child objects.

There's no LINQ-to-SQL or EF Core code in the question. EF Core neither has nor needs extra "repositories" and "units of work", a DbContext already is a Unit-of-Work. You don't need to specify JOINs on the client with EF Core. If you have a Customer.Address or Customer.Addresses property, EF itself will generate JOINs as needed. All this code could be just context.Customers.Select(c=> new {CustomerName=c.Name,Addresses=c.Addresses.ToList()}). Add Select before ToList to select specific fields only

Hi Panagiotis, thanks for your reply. This application works with repo and uow.

No, the application isn't using either Repository or Unit-of-Work, because those are provided by EF. There's no EF code here. This looks like an attempt to follow a Bad Practices article that claims to implement Repository by wrapping a high-level multi-entity disconnected UoW (ie DbContext) into a single table CRUD class. CRUD classes aren't repositories. Best case, those are just wrappers over DbContext and DbSet and All() doesn't return all data, just a DbSet<T>.AsQueryable(). Worst case, optimistic concurrency is broken and you have to use explicit database transactions

EF already provides a repo (DBSet) and UoW (DbContext). If your own Repository pattern is returning IQueryable<TEntity> and you are leveraging navigation properties like you should (The whole point of using an ORM in the first place) then:
var results = await _unitOfWork.customerRepository.All()
    .Select(c => new CustomerResponse
    {
        CustomerName = c.Name
        Addresses = c.Addresses.Select(a => new AddressResponse
        {
            AddressName = a.Name
            AddressNo = a.Number
        }).ToList();
    }).ToListAsync();

You can do the same with the Linq from/select syntax, that's just down to personal preference. But what I don't recommend is using EF + Linq as a straight substitute to writing SQL in C#, especially with an additional abstraction over-top EF's DbSets. This completely defeats the purpose of using Entity Framework. There are very few cases where you should ever need to use an explicit Join in EF, and those are situations where there is no direct FK relationship between tables. In all normal situations where there are FKs you should use navigation properties (one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many, etc.) and let EF manage the joins. It is what EF is built to do.

You need to group the addresses per customer so that you can return one CustomerResponse per customer with a collection of addresses as child objects. You can grupy customer by name and then combine adresses into it
 var query = from customer in _unitOfWork.customerRepository.All()
        join address in _unitOfWork.AdresRepository.All() on customer.adressNo equals address.adressNo into adr
        from address in adr.DefaultIfEmpty()
        group address by new { customer.Name} into grouped
        select new CustomerResponse
        {
            CustomerName = grouped.Key.Name,
            Addresses = grouped
                .Where(a => a != null)
                .Select(a => new Address
                {
                    adressName = a.name,
                    adressNo = a.Number
                })
                .ToList()
        };


Hi Aquasoser, tnx for your reply. I will try it out and let you know

@user3552264 if you used EF properly you wouldn't have to group in memory after the fact. EF itself would produce the correct results as StevePy's answer shows.
